# How to check Global Reversible Encryption though JNA?

Tags: java, windows, jna

I am trying to retrieve the global value of the `Reversible Encryption` setting in Windows through JNA (Java Native Access) programmatically.

I am able to read other values from the Global user password policy via JNA such as

1. Enforce password history
2. Maximum password age
3. Minimum password age
4. Minimum password length

But there is no information on how you can get specifically the value of Reversible Encryption in Java? I tried to google but to no avail. Anyone knows?

Answer (score 0):

The reversible encryption setting is available in WMI in the [RSOP_SecuritySettingBoolean](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375062(v=vs.85).aspx) class, using the key `ClearTextPassword`.

It is possible to query WMI via the command line (e.g., `wmic /NAMESPACE:\\root\RSOP\Computer path RSOP_SecuritySettingBoolean`) or through powershell.  I have implemented a [WMI Util class using JNA](https://github.com/oshi/oshi/blob/279a6f2dbcc8a68b55f6d1a4c0ec5e6808c96593/oshi-core/src/main/java/oshi/util/platform/windows/WmiUtil.java) that implements C code to query WMI that you are welcome to copy if you'd prefer a programmatic approach (you'll need a few more classes there.)

You can also execute this on the command line: `Secedit.exe /export /cfg c:\cfg.txt` and read the output file, looking for the value of `ClearTextPassword`.

It also looks like you can possibly [fetch the value with a binary dump of the contents](http://www.beginningtoseethelight.org/ntsecurity/index.htm#BB4F910C0FFA1E43) of registry key `\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SAM\SAM\Domains\Account\F` in which case the value would be stored in the 4 most significant bits of the byte at offset 0x004C.  You can read the registry using [JNA's Advapi32Util class](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.4.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Advapi32Util.html) (in this case, probably [`registryGetBinaryValue()`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.4.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Advapi32Util.html#registryGetBinaryValue-com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinReg.HKEY-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)).

I also found a registry location that may be helpful (completely untested):
`\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SeCEdit\Reg Values`. This points to similar settings in `Machine/System/CurrentControlSet/Services/Netlogon/Parameters` which may or may not be helpful

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. The one with Secedit.exe seems a simple solution however you must save to a file first before reading it. It is not suitable for the ProcessBuilder class in Java. I was wondering if there is a suitable Java API to read values in the registry key?

Comment: JNA's `Advapi32Util` class has methods for reading registry keys. I've updated my answer with links.

Comment: Yes the `Advapi32Util` class is perfect. But, it seems this registry key `\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SAM\SAM\Domains\Account\F` is not guaranteed to exist. So `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SecEdit` shows the local policy data is stored in the database file located in `C:\WINDOWS\Security\Database\secedit.sdb` You can view the data by running `Secedit.exe /export /cfg c:\cfg.txt`. That is exactly where you need to read the value of `ClearTextPassword`. Is there another way that we can use JNA to query the secedit.sdb database, perhaps talking to a DLL file?

Comment: I can't find any documentation of the `.sdb` format.  It appears `secedit.exe` is the only documented way of accessing it.   It does use the [scecli.dll](http://www.win7dll.info/scecli_dll.html) DLL file, but that's not documented; you can get the method names but no signatures.

Comment: Check out `\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SeCEdit\Reg Values`

Comment: Thanks. Looks like my best solution is to dump the output of `secedit.exe` to a file temporarily, reads the values in a singleton object and then delete the file afterwards, but it may pose a possible security risk, however.

Comment: Did you try the WMI approach?

Comment: No, I have not tried the RSOP_SecuritySettingBoolean class yet, I am not sure how to implement and retrieve values from a C++ class and put them into my Java code? Do you have any example code for this?

Comment: Microsoft has published [C code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390423(v=VS.85).aspx) for retrieving WMI which I have implemented in the `WMIUtil` class I referenced in my answer.  As an intermediate/test step, however, you can just implement the `wmic` command line version of the same query, or you can call `powershell.exe` with appropriate arguments as well.

Comment: I am not familar with querying WMI. Can you please elaborate a bit more about how it can be achieved to fetch the value of ClearTextPassword via JNA? Perhaps some code examples would be helpful if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: For exploratory purposes just use the `wmic` command line. I posted a sample query in my answer.  There's a different syntax for powershell queries that you could also use on the command line.   For using JNA to query WMI I posted a link in my answer to the WMIUtil class I wrote for the OSHI project.  There are many other examples in that project in the various Windows classes which use the WMIUtil methods.

Comment: I decided to learn Powershell this time to help me understand the RSOP_SecuritySettingBoolean class first. 

Below is what I executed but it returned nothing.

`PS E:\> Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\RSOP\Computer" -Query "SELECT setting FROM RSOP_SecuritySettingBoolean Where KeyN
ame='ClearTextPassword' and precedence='1'"`

Question - does the RSOP_SecuritySettingBoolean class exist in every Windows system, including Windows 10 Pro which I use here?

Comment: The documentation says that class has been in since Vista / Server2003.  On my system (Win 7) I get "No Instance".   I'd recommend actually changing your setting and seeing if that class returns something; it's entirely possible that it simply returns nothing for "false" or "zero" which is the default for that setting.

Comment: I have simplied the query to list all values `Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\RSOP\Computer" -Query "SELECT * FROM RSOP_SecuritySettingBoolean"`. It returned nothing. I need to research more and understand the reason. Will post once I find it.

Comment: I was thinking maybe the easier solution would be to create a small DLL file with a simple function in C to read the value of the reversible encryption setting. Then use JNA to call this DLL file to get the value. If this approach would work, do I need a MSVC (express version) compiler installed and copy the C code https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390423(v=VS.85).aspx that you mentioned before, modify it for DLL, compile it and pack it in the jar file? Would it work?